# Сделать include_once файла в корне

Tags: php

Как правильно указать url для include_once от вложенного на 3 и более уровней файла, к function.php который лежит в корне?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/function.php'

Comment: сделай проще константу, например define("HOME",
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);